# Error in UseMethod("filter") : no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Tags: tidyverse, tidymodels, r-recipes, ensembles

I am actually using Tidymodels package on R to study a multi-class classification problem. I have trained several models using Workflow sets, and in my recipe I added a step taken [there](https://github.com/tidymodels/recipes/issues/473) to replace NA values with a constant. The models that I included in the workflow are:

```
mlp <-
  mlp(hidden_units = tune(), penalty = tune(), epochs = tune()) %>%
  set_engine('nnet') %>%
  set_mode('classification')

multinom <-
  multinom_reg(penalty = tune(), mixture = tune()) %>%
  set_engine('glmnet')

rand_forest <-
  rand_forest(mtry = tune(), min_n = tune()) %>%
  set_engine('ranger') %>%
  set_mode('classification')

tabnet <- tabnet(mode="classification", batch_size= 126, virtual_batch_size= 128, epochs= 1,
                 num_steps = tune(), learn_rate = tune())%>%
  set_engine("torch", verbose = TRUE)
```

For some models I tried a recipe with SMOTE ("themis" package), PCA, and normalisation (all in the same workflow by adding the steps to the original recipe). Training and testing went pretty well, so I tried an ensemble of these models (using the package "stacks"):

```
  tidymodels_prefer()
  
    stack1 <- 
    stacks() %>% 
    add_candidates(res_1)
  
 
  set.seed(2002)
   res1_stack <-
     stack1 %>%
    blend_predictions()

ens <- fit_members(res1_stack)
```

When I run this last operation (fit_members) I receive this error

```
Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

I figured out, reading [this](https://github.com/spsanderson/healthyR.ai/commit/89671ff138e61d07a5dbdfcd7e0a694144aa3e08) and [this](https://github.com/spsanderson/healthyR.ai/issues/81) on GitHub, that it was because the added step "constantimpute" to the recipe. However, I don't exactly know how can I fix it. Someone can help me?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Can you create a minimal [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) that only includes enough lines of code to recreate the error? To echo what Max mentioned in your linked [github issue](https://github.com/tidymodels/recipes/issues/473), I don't think imputing with an arbitrary constant is necessarily a good idea from a modeling perspective. I'd recommend a different imputation strategy - [recipes](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/reference/index.html#step-functions-imputation) gives a lot of options for imputing missing data.

Comment: Is your custom recipe in a package, or defined in your script only? To be used in the broader tidymodels ecosystem, [you typically need more infrastructure for a recipe step and to put it in a package](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/develop/recipes/#other-step-methods).

Answer (score 0):

Before using the filter function, make sure the table you want to filter is loaded.
Most times we have the the view() function applied and this prevents the table from being loaded into memory for usage.